# Spacy custom POS tagging for medical concepts

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, spacy

We are a group of doctors trying to use linguistic features of "Spacy", especially the part of speech tagging to show relationships between medical concepts like:

***'Femoral artery pseudoaneurysm***  as in ==>

**"femoral artery" ['Anatomical Location']  --> and "pseudoaneurysm" ['Pathology']**

We are new to NLP and spacy, can someone with experience with NLP and Spacy explain if this is a good approach to show these relationships in medical documents? If not what are the other alternative methods?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the example, it looks like you need more than simple POS tagging. Thankfully there is a full subdomain of NLP devoted to biomedical data, and there are many tools available which can help with this kind of task:

- In case the data is made of biomedical research papers, you will find a lot of resources related to the [Medline](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/medline/medline_overview.html) and [PubMedCentral](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/) databases:

  - [UMLS](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/research/umls/index.html) and the tool [MetaMap](https://metamap.nlm.nih.gov/)
  - [PubTator](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/research/pubtator/), a recent annotated version of the biomedical literature.
  - [SemRep](https://lhncbc.nlm.nih.gov/ii/tools/SemRep_SemMedDB_SKR/SemRep.html) for relations.
- [cTakes](https://ctakes.apache.org/) is another annotator system which is more specialized with clinical texts.
- [SciSpacy](https://allenai.github.io/scispacy/) is a Spacy variant specialized for biomedical text. It can also annotate medical terms with UMLS labels.

The last one in particular seems particularly appropriate in your case. biomedical text presents a lot of specific difficulties which cannot be handled with general domain models.

Note that there are probably more tools and resources, this a very active domain.

(disclaimer: I recycled a large part of an [older answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/90124/64377))

Comment: Dear Erwan thanks for your answer. I had a look at your old answer as well. Very useful links.